# Why do I get an error while trying to append input float to an array?

Tags: python, arrays

```
from array import *
a=array('i',[])
for i in range (5):
    x = float(input("enter the element of array:"))
    a.append(x)
for i in range (5):
    print(a[i], end="  ")
```

ouput:

> enter the element of array:3.5
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)     in ()
> 5 for i in range (5):
> 6     x=float(input("enter the element of array:"))
> ----> 7     a.append(x)
> 8 for i in range (5):
> 9     print (a[i],end="  ")
>
> TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Answer (score 7):

Use `"f"` for a float array. `"i"` indicates a signed int array. See the [`array` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html).

```
a = array ('f', [])
```

For more precision, use a double array.

```
a = array('d', [])
```

Comment: which i input i expect that , but i can't get, i get learge value, what is the solution behind it ??

Comment: @MehediHasanRony You can use a double array: `a = array('d', [])`